# The physical meaning of radius of convergence

Tags: mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory

If y(x) is a power series convergent around $x_0$ with the radius $|x-x_0|<R$, what is the physical meaning? Can I understand that the item $|x-x_0|$ can be one of the dominating factors for the value of y(x) if $|x-x_0|<R$? or how to understand it in perturbation theory?

Comment: What is the context of this question? A mathematical formula by itself cannot have a physical meaning.

Comment: There's no physical relevance - it's of purely mathematical significance.

Answer (score 1):

The radius of convergence of a (complex) power series is a purely mathematical concept. It could have some practical significance in the Taylor series expansion used in physical models because expansions with $|x-x_0|> R$ will not converge. So this is a definite limit for the frequently used Taylor series approximation.

Answer (score 0):

[Kato](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf#page=87) p.64 gives some examples of 2x2 matrices for which the eigenvalues are analytic functions with "exceptional points". These points limit the radius of convergence of the perturbation series.